# what is the proper way to style columns width in table?

Tags: css

How to style this table so that first column is X pixels wide and second Y pixels wide. What is the best way to style it? I guess adding class to every TD is not the way to go. Should I use COL and style it?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your browser support requirements, you might consider styling a colgroup.  For tables, I've always just set the `width` on the `td`s in the first row.

Comment: From my experience it is enough but is is really the proper way?

Answer (score 3):

**CSS** is the proper way to style HTML.

Use CSS class names as you normally do on other tags.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class='col1'></td>
  <td class='col2'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.col1 {
   width:100px
}

.col2 {
   width:120px
}
```